# I wanna select 2 different inputs(radio buttons) and divide their value and show the result as alert

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
 <form id="payments" >
          <input type="radio" id="firstpay" name="pay" value="999" >
            <label for="firpay">999 €</label>
            <input type="radio" id="secondpay" name="pay" value="1599" >
            <label for="firpay">1599 €</label>
            <input type="radio" id="thirdpay" name="pay" value="2999">
            <label for="firpay">2999 €</label>
         </form>
```

So i select 1 input from here and one from below:

```
 <input name="answer" id="answer_1" type="radio" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="answer" id="answer_2" type="radio" value="7">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="answer" id="answer_3" type="radio" value="15">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="answer" id="answer_4" type="radio" value="24">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="answer" id="answer_5" type="radio" value="36">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="answer" id="answer_6" type="radio" value="50">
```

So lets say i select input with id firstpay and when i select other inputs from the second form i wanna get ( 999 / 0 , 7 , 15...) depending on the second input. I want the result to come as alert

Comment: This should be done using javascript. What have you tried till now?

Comment: All your `<label>` elements are associated with the same (non-existent) ”firpay” element. You seem to have one group of elements inside a `<form>` element and another group somewhere else in a `<table>`? You haven’t shown any attempt at a solution to your own problem, (please show your “*[mcve]*”).

Comment: @TusharShahi I tried with javascript but I'm a noob

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I haven`t shown a solution because I don`t have one if I did I will not be asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track the values of pay and answer. 
Register 'change' event for input, When both values available show the alert. Try the snippet.

```js
const track = {
  pay: null,
  answer: null,
};

document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const type = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    track[type] = value;

    if (track.pay !== null && track.answer !== null) {
      alert(
        `Avg is ${track.pay} / ${track.answer} = ${track.pay / track.answer}`
      );
    }
  })
);
```

```html
<form id="payments" >
   <input type="radio" id="firstpay" name="pay" value="999" >
   <label for="firpay">999 €</label>
   <input type="radio" id="secondpay" name="pay" value="1599" >
   <label for="firpay">1599 €</label>
   <input type="radio" id="thirdpay" name="pay" value="2999">
   <label for="firpay">2999 €</label>
</form>


<td>
   <input name="answer" id="answer_1" type="radio" value="0">
</td>
<td>
   <input name="answer" id="answer_2" type="radio" value="7">
</td>
<td>
   <input name="answer" id="answer_3" type="radio" value="15">
</td>
<td>
   <input name="answer" id="answer_4" type="radio" value="24">
</td>
<td>
   <input name="answer" id="answer_5" type="radio" value="36">
</td>
<td>
   <input name="answer" id="answer_6" type="radio" value="50"> 
</td>
```